# New version of Android Studio is missing Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

So for some reasons I had to uninstall Android Studio and all its components from my computer and went ahead and downloaded the new version from the oficial website [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Other). I followed all the installation steps but the Android SDK is not being installed. There is no option to install it during the installation process:

[image]

If I proceed with the installation I will get a message when I run Android Studio that there is no Android SDK path specified. Well since there was no option to install it there is no SDK files in my computer. I even checked the default paths where the SDK are located but no success. I also can't find a download link for the SDK anywhere, just the link from the official website that comes with no SDK to install. Can someone please help me? Am I missing something?

**EDIT 1**

As requested by CommonsWare, this is what pops up when I first run Android Studio after the installation is completed:

[image]

If I click on the link provided where it says I can get the SDK files, I get redirected to the page where I downloaded the Android Studio installer.

Comment: While a few SDK bits may come packaged with the Android Studio installer, most are downloaded on first run of Studio. The file size of the Windows installer is comparable to that of the other platforms, and so you should have all the same bits that everyone else has. You might want to take screenshots of what you are seeing when you run first run Studio after installation, and show us where you get this "no Android SDK path specified" error.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks

Comment: Strange... my best guess is that when you removed the older copy of Studio, it left something behind that tripped up the new copy of Studio. Glad you have it working, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK path is usually C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.

Kindly browse for your Android SDK path and mention the same path when asked for choosing an SDK.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that.